Continuous time Markov chain question regarding steady state distribution
I am currently working on this question:
Consider a job shop that has 3 identical machines and 3 tech- nicians. Suppose that the amount of time each machine operates before breaking down is exponentially distributed with rate parameter 0.1, while the time that a technician takes to fix a broken machine is exponentially dsitributed with rate parameter 0.5. Suppose that all the times to breakdown and times to repair are independent random variables and let X(t) denote the number of operating machines at time t > 0.
(a) Determine the Q-matrix of the Markov process.
(b) What is the proportion of machines that are idle in the long run?
My working for a) I defined 4 states and assigned probabilities for transitions and calculated diagonal elements of the Q matrix by adding together exit probabilities. This is what I have:
State 3 -> 2: 30.1
State 2->1: 20.1
State 1->0: 10.1
0-> 1: 30.5
1->2: 20.5
2->3: 30.5
Diagonal elements:
Exit out of 0: 0->=1,5
Exit out of 1: 1->0 + 1 -> 2 = 1 +0.1 = 1.1
Exit out of 2: 2->1 +2->3 = 0.2 + 0.5 = 0.7
Exit out of 3: 3->2: 0.3.
Hence,
Q = \begin{pmatrix}
-1.5 & 1.5 & 0 & 0 \\
0.1 & -1.1 & 1.0 & 0 \\
0 & 0.2 & -0.7 & 0.5 \\
0 & 0 & 0.3 & -0.3
\end{pmatrix}
Not sure what to do after this. Especially for question B. I am unable to conceptually approach how to find the proportion of idle machines. I have a feeling it is regarding steady state distributions due to the mention of long-run probability. Help with the other questions will also be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance :)

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Plan: (1) Find the stationary distribution $\pi$. That is, find the probability distribution $\pi=(\pi_0,\pi_1,\pi_2,\pi_3)$ such that $\pi Q=0$ .
(2) Can you express the "proportion of machines that are idle in the long run" in terms of some or all of the elements of $\pi$?
